# Less CSS unneeded @import downsides

Tags: less

I have a project with CSS directory structure like this:

```
-public
-admin
-includes
```

Is there any downside of making a "importer" file in *includes* folder which would just contain `@import` for all files within that directory? And then just include that file in every file in public/admin directory. It isn't necessary to load them all always but its way cleaner that way than importing dependencies manually on top of each file.

I guess it will compile them a bit slower probably since it has to read more files but it would save me way more time and cares to stop thinking about dependencies in projects. Do I lose something doing this or is it absolutely ok?

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach sound good. I normally think splitting up code in files is a good idea if you structure it good and load it into 1 file at run-time (with less compiler or so). That way it is easier to structure it, easier to find what you need. For me that wins over the small negative of extra time for the compiler.